# Syntax error when attempting to amend a string with indexing

Tags: indexing, variable-assignment, in-place, apl, dyalog

I'm studying APL from [here](https://www.dyalog.com/uploads/documents/MasteringDyalogAPL.pdf).

Why am I getting this syntax error?

```
      'computer' [ 1 2 3 ] ← 'COM'
SYNTAX ERROR
'computer'[1 2 3]←'COM'
          ^
```

But if I save `'computer'` in a variable I don't get the error:

```
      T ← 'computer'
      T
computer
      T[1 2 3] ← 'COM'
      T
COMputer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'computer'` is a constant, and you can't change the value of a constant itself, only the current value of a variable.

Think about it: If you could assign to `'computer'`, then next time you wrote `'computer'`, would you expect the result to be `COMputer`? How about `2←3`? Clearly, this doesn't make any sense.

However, you *can* amend a value without assigning it to a name, using the relatively new `@` "at" operator (it isn't included in *Mastering Dyalog APL*, but [the documentation is available online](http://help.dyalog.com/latest/Content/Language/Primitive%20Operators/At.htm)).

```
      'COM'@1 2 3⊢'computer'
COMputer
```

You can read this as *put the letters 'COM' **at** indices 1 2 3 of the word 'computer'*. The `⊢` here only serves to separate `1 2 3` from `'computer` so it is clear to `@` what constitutes the indices and what is the array to be amended.

[Run it on TryAPL!](https://tryapl.org/?a=%27COM%27@1%202%203%u22A2%27computer%27&run)

Answer (score 2):

That bracket notation is made specifically for modifying variables. The return value of `T[1 2 3] ← 'COM'` is `'COM'`, so if the expression didn't modify a variable, it would be pointless (or, almost identical to `⊢`).

To get a modified array, not modify a variable, use the operator [`@`](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/index_Left.htm#CSHID=Language%2FPrimitive%2520Operators%2FAt.htm|StartTopic=Content%2FLanguage%2FPrimitive%2520Operators%2FAt.htm|SkinName=Default):

```
('COM'@1 2 3) 'computer'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBCEKj9omKKgn5@cWlJakFqlzcakXpRaX5pQo5KcppFYUADnFmfl5Vupcj7oWKYREGyoYKRjHQjQ5@/uC1KtzqYcl5pSmgnSEABWGQMRCizPz0hUcgAIaYJUOYK2aSHYBAA)