# How can I do this operation without parens?

Tags: apl

[Here](https://tryretool.com/blog/the-slide-rule/?4) I read that "The Babylonians came up with the "quarter-square multiplication", which reduces multiplication to subtraction:

```
a*b = (a+b)^2/4 - (a-b)^2/4
```

When I tried this in APL I ended up with this:

```
(((a + b) * 2) ÷ 4) - (((a - b) * 2) ÷ 4)
```

But isn't this ugly with all these parens? I Could't figure out how to put "`÷ 4`" before "`(a + b) * 2)`" so that it is executed last according to "right to left" rule.

Comment: I assume you are using Dyalog APL due to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52928337/5306507), but it would be worth mentioning this in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the `⍨` "commute" operator. It takes a single function and derives a new function identical to the old, but with arguments swapped:

```
      5-2
3
      5-⍨2
¯3
```

So your formula can be written as:

```
(4 ÷⍨ 2 *⍨ a + b) - (4 ÷⍨ 2*⍨ a - b)
```

[The full documentation is here.](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/Symbols/Dieresis%20Tilde.htm)

Comment: And instead of dividing by 4, you can multiply with .25 which takes out two commutes: `(.25 × 2 *⍨ a + b) - (.25 × 2*⍨ a - b)` (I think in this case the shorter version is ever more readable ;-))

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I've never seen APL before, so this may not be idiomatic. But it's just a programming language; how hard can it be?)

I've come up with the following, which uses no parentheses at all:

```
-/2*⍨0.5×a+b×1 ¯1
```

Algorithm:

- Create an array containing `[1, -1]`.
- Multiply each element by `b`, giving `[b, -b]`.
- Add `a` to each element, giving `[a+b, a-b]`.
- Multiply each element by 1/2 (0.5), giving `[(a+b)/2, (a-b)/2]`.
- Square each element (using the commute operator `⍨` to put the exponent on the left), giving `[((a+b)/2)^2, ((a-b)/2)^2]`, which is equivalent to `[(a+b)^2 / 4, (a-b)^2 / 4]`.
- Subtract the elements from each other, giving `(a+b)^2 / 4 - (a-b)^2 / 4`.

Comment: There are ways to combine the operations, but while your solution works on scalar `a` and `b`, [it fails on non-scalars](https://tryapl.org/?a=a%u21903%202%20%u22C4%20b%u21904%20%u22C4%20-/2*%u23680.5%D7a+b%D71%20%AF1%20%u22C4%20%284%20%F7%u2368%202%20*%u2368%20a%20+%20b%29%20-%20%284%20%F7%u2368%202*%u2368%20a%20-%20b%29&run).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be so late to the party, but here's a solution with only one set of parens -- the phrase inside the parens is a [Train](http://wiki.nars2000.org/index.php/Trains) where `a (f g h) b ←→ (a f b) g a h b`:

```
-⌿4 ÷⍨ 2 *⍨ a (+ ,[⎕IO-0.5] -) b
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one couple of ()

```
  4÷⍨-/2*⍨(+/,-/)10 2
20
```